# Как создать калькулятор?

Tags: javascript, база-данных

Меня интересует создание своеобразного калькулятора, в общем:

1. Человек должен зарегистрироваться на сайте
2. Внести в определенную таблицу цифры, и они должны сохраниться в БД, исключительно для этого человека
3. Через какое-то время он в эту же таблицу вносит уже новые цифры, и **из новых чисел вычитаются старые.** Например, сначала он ввел 4, в следующий раз 7, по скрипту должно произойти вычитание 7-4=3 и вывестись значение на экран. **Так должно происходить с каждым новым вводом чисел.**

Вот я и хотел узнать, как создать подобную БД, и какие операторы нужны для такой операции? И нужно ли что-то еще для осуществления этого?

Comment: кто захочет регистрироваться на сайте, чтоб сложить два числа?

Comment: @dDevil это образно, чтобы суть была ясна. В конце будет таблица, по которой можно отслеживать все изменения.

Comment: Вы принципиально хотите сделать это на JavaScript?